# Batch file to copy file A to file B after removing the CR LF

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a batch file contents to copy file A to file B after removing the CR LF

I have found the following but it is simply taking actual value of %1 and putting into a file without cr lf.

```
 REM Copy and Remove Line Feeds
 @echo off
 echo %1>  %2

 rem <nul set /p ".=%1 > c:/temp/%2.txt
```

I need to remove all the CR LFs from File A and put the results in File B

Answer (score 3):

The Batch file below do what you want in the fastest way:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
   set /P "=%%a" < NUL
)) > %2
```

You must put files A and B in the parameters: test.bat A.txt B.txt

Antonio

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of free 3rd party utilities that could be downloaded to make this task easy.

I have written a REPL.BAT hybrid batch/JScript utility that conveinently performs regex search and replace on files. It is extremely flexible and quite fast.

It is very easy to do what you want with this utility.

```
type A.txt|repl "\r|\n" "" m >B.txt
```

Here is the REPL.BAT script. Full documentation is embedded within the script:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
:::
:::REPL  Search  Replace  [Options  [SourceVar]]
:::REPL  /?
:::
:::  Performs a global search and replace operation on each line of input from
:::  stdin and prints the result to stdout.
:::
:::  Each parameter may be optionally enclosed by double quotes. The double
:::  quotes are not considered part of the argument. The quotes are required
:::  if the parameter contains a batch token delimiter like space, tab, comma,
:::  semicolon. The quotes should also be used if the argument contains a
:::  batch special character like &, |, etc. so that the special character
:::  does not need to be escaped with ^.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /? then prints help documentation
:::  to stdout.
:::
:::  Search  - By default this is a case sensitive JScript (ECMA) regular
:::            expression expressed as a string.
:::
:::            JScript syntax documentation is available at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Replace - By default this is the string to be used as a replacement for
:::            each found search expression. Full support is provided for
:::            substituion patterns available to the JScript replace method.
:::            A $ literal can be escaped as $$. An empty replacement string
:::            must be represented as "".
:::
:::            Replace substitution pattern syntax is documented at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Options - An optional string of characters used to alter the behavior
:::            of REPL. The option characters are case insensitive, and may
:::            appear in any order.
:::
:::            I - Makes the search case-insensitive.
:::
:::            L - The Search is treated as a string literal instead of a
:::                regular expression. Also, all $ found in Replace are
:::                treated as $ literals.
:::
:::            E - Search and Replace represent the name of environment
:::                variables that contain the respective values. An undefined
:::                variable is treated as an empty string.
:::
:::            M - Multi-line mode. The entire contents of stdin is read and
:::                processed in one pass instead of line by line. ^ anchors
:::                the beginning of a line and $ anchors the end of a line.
:::
:::            X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
:::                for the following escape sequences:
:::
:::                \\     -  Backslash
:::                \b     -  Backspace
:::                \f     -  Formfeed
:::                \n     -  Newline
:::                \r     -  Carriage Return
:::                \t     -  Horizontal Tab
:::                \v     -  Vertical Tab
:::                \xnn   -  Ascii (Latin 1) character expressed as 2 hex digits
:::                \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
:::
:::                Escape sequences are supported even when the L option is used.
:::
:::            S - The source is read from an environment variable instead of
:::                from stdin. The name of the source environment variable is
:::                specified in the next argument after the option string.
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
if .%2 equ . (
  if "%~1" equ "/?" (
    findstr "^:::" "%~f0" | cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^:::" ""
    exit /b 0
  ) else (
    call :err "Insufficient arguments"
    exit /b 1
  )
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "[^SMILEX]" >nul && (
  call :err "Invalid option(s)"
  exit /b 1
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use REPL /? to get help.
exit /b

************* JScript portion **********/
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var search=args.Item(0);
var replace=args.Item(1);
var options="g";
if (args.length>2) {
  options+=args.Item(2).toLowerCase();
}
var multi=(options.indexOf("m")>=0);
var srcVar=(options.indexOf("s")>=0);
if (srcVar) {
  options=options.replace(/s/g,"");
}
if (options.indexOf("e")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/e/g,"");
  search=env(search);
  replace=env(replace);
}
if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/l/g,"");
  search=search.replace(/([.^$*+?()[{\\|])/g,"\\$1");
  replace=replace.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$");
}
if (options.indexOf("x")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/x/g,"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
    function($0,$1,$2){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
    }
  );
  replace=replace.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
}
var search=new RegExp(search,options);

if (srcVar) {
  WScript.Stdout.Write(env(args.Item(3)).replace(search,replace));
} else {
  while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
    if (multi) {
      WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(search,replace));
    } else {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().replace(search,replace));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! .. this covers the full scope of what I need to do with the file.  I copied to a BAT file and ran with the parameters you specified.  It ran without reporting errors and opened File A.  It created File B but file B is empty.  I double checked my parameters and no typos.  I'll read through your doc later to see if its a parameter issue - have to run for now.   Best regards .. back later

Comment: @user1868232 - I tested those parameters on a number of text files, large and small, and it worked perfectly for me. I have no idea what is going wrong on your end.